# Suspend after Boot

Tags: elementary-website

Thanks for this support forum...

Recently I install Elementary OS for my laptop, and I make dual boot with Windows 10 but strange happen... Every time I turn it on before the login screen elementary OS always suspend so I have to press power again to make the login screen appear. It's annoying for me because of that. Can anyone help me about this problem.